# Marketing Cloud send syncronized Data Extension information to Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, data, journeybuilder, extension

i just setted up my Sales cloud integration in MC. Im now able to see my "Lead" Data in MC syncr. Data extensions.

But i cant get the Data into a normal Data Extension to work with the information i get from Salesforce.

What is the best practice to send data from synchronized Ext. to another Data Extensiion i can use in Journey Builder?

Hope you can help me out.

Thank you

Seb.

Comment: Consider using a query to project data from one data extension to another.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is the bad news. We have enabled synchronized data extensions and while they work, the "query feature" doesn't appear to function with them. Also, if you use a filter to move the data into a new data extension the resulting data extension created by the filter will end up in the synchronized data extension folder and then can't be moved or deleted.  It's hard to say anyone did any testing with this.